# Transform union type to intersection type

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to transform a union type into an intersection type :

```
type FunctionUnion = (() => void) | ((p: string) => void)
type FunctionIntersection = (() => void) & ((p: string) => void)
```

I would like to apply a transformation to `FunctionUnion` to get `FunctionIntersection`

Answer (score 438, accepted):

You want union to intersection?  [Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) and [inference from conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) can do that.  (Don't think it's possible to do intersection-to-union though, sorry) Here's the evil magic:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (x: U)=>void : never) extends ((x: infer I)=>void) ? I : never
```

That distributes the union `U` and repackages it into a new union where all the consitutents are in contravariant position.  That allows the type to be inferred as an intersection `I`, as mentioned in the handbook:

> Likewise, multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred.

---

Let's see if it works.

First let me parenthesize your `FunctionUnion` and `FunctionIntersection` because TypeScript seems to bind the union/intersection more tightly than function return:

```
type FunctionUnion = (() => void) | ((p: string) => void);
type FunctionIntersection = (() => void) & ((p: string) => void);
```

Testing:

```
type SynthesizedFunctionIntersection = UnionToIntersection<FunctionUnion>
// inspects as 
// type SynthesizedFunctionIntersection = (() => void) & ((p: string) => void)
```

Looks good!

Be careful that in general `UnionToIntersection<>` exposes some details of what TypeScript thinks is an actual union.  For example, `boolean` is apparently internally represented as `true | false`, so

```
type Weird = UnionToIntersection<string | number | boolean>
```

becomes

```
type Weird = string & number & true & false
```

which in TS3.6+ gets eagerly reduced to

```
type Weird = never
```

because it's impossible to have a value which is `string` *and* `number` *and* `true` *and* `false`.

Comment: 10x. I always learn new an interesting things from you. I was very close on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50369299/can-i-reuse-the-parameter-definition-of-a-function-in-typescript/50375712#50375712 but really need a way to transform the union into an intersection

Comment: This answer is awesome but I really find it hard to understand how this part "That distributes the union U and repackages it into a new union where all the consitutents are in **contravariant position**" works :(

I can't fully grasp this _contravariant position_ part. .I thought that this code: `type Param<T> = T extends (arg: infer U) => void ? U : never;` `type InferredParams = Param<((a: string) => void) | ((a: number) => void)>;` should give me `string & number` but it gives me `string | number`. Can you explain why?

Comment: I thought I would understand this answer when I would "split" it up. Like that: `type UnionToIntersectionPart1<U> = U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never;
type UnionToIntersectionPart2<U> = U extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;
type IntersectionTest = UnionToIntersectionPart2<
  UnionToIntersectionPart1<(() => void) | ((p: string) => void)>
>;` But then it doesn't work! `IntersectionTest` is still union of function types, not intersection.

Comment: It's because bare type parameters before `extends` in a conditional type are [distributed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) across any union constituents.  If you want to disable distributed conditional types, you can use the trick of making the type parameter "clothed", such as a single-element tuple like this: `type Param<T> = [T] extends [(arg: infer U) => void] ? U : never;`.  That should work the way you want.

Comment: Could you explain the beginning part with `U extends any ?` ?
I tried just `((a: U) => void) extends (a: infer I) => void ? I : never;` but it doesn't work, even though the type U => void that's generated should be the same.

Comment: @RanLottem the key is [distributive conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types).  The handbook explains it pretty well, in my opinion.  I've [expanded on it elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383816/2887218) you need more info.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz is there a way to use this to get the intersection of union types?




`type X = (string | null) & (string | number); /* string */
type Y = UnionToIntersection<(string | null) | (string | number)>; /*null & string & number */`

Comment: Unions are associative, so `(string | null) | (string | number)` is just one big union `string | number | null`.  There's nothing for `UnionToIntersection<>` to act on; it's too late.  If you have the chance to alter the original elements before uniting them, you can do it (e.g., `UnionToIntersection<[string | null] | [string | number]>[0]`)

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this trick, it really made things much nicer to work with!

Comment: @jcalz When properties of the union types have the same name but different types, can we make this somehow pick the type of the property from the first (or last) item in the union? Basically, here's an example: https://gitter.im/Microsoft/TypeScript?at=5dd06d64e75b2d5a19e5c911

Comment: Unions in TypeScript are unordered in principle (... and although in practice the compiler does store the constituents in *some* order, the particular order is not guaranteed to make any sense or be stable from one compile to the next, so you can't rely on it).  So any type manipulation that relies on being able to inspect unions for order is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type).

Comment: I modified the answer answer above to handle the case of never, which resolves to unknown with the example above. Thanks to @jcalz for the tip:
```type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    ([U] extends [never] ? never :
        (U extends any
            ? ((k: U) => void)
            : never
        ) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never);
```

Comment: @NicholasCuthbert be careful; `unknown` is the "correct" result. For all `A` and `B`, `UTI<A | B>` should equal `UTI<A> & UTI<B>`, right? Let `B` be `never` and note `A | never` is `A`. Now you have `UTI<A> = UTI<A> & UTI<never>` for all `A`. The only reasonable way to satisfy that is `UTI<never>`=`unknown`, since `X & unknown` is equal to `X`. If `UTI<never>` were `never`, then `UTI<A> = UTI<A> & never`, but since `X & never`=`never`, you're saying `UTI<A> = never` for all `A`... not great. There may be use cases for `UTI<never>` to be `never`, but it's not apparent to me, so be careful.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the reply. What you say does make sense for the general case. Our use case should be fine since I'm trying to get the intersection of all arguments to a set of functions, and if a single argument is never, that implies that the function should never be called.

Comment: @jcalz this appears to be broken for Typescript 3.6.3+. The type Weird is evaluating to never. Do you know how I fix it?

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.6.3#code/FAFwngDgpgBAqgOwJYHsEBUUEkEigJwGcoBjEVBAHjgD4YBeGYGFmACjhigA88EATQjACGCMDAD87ANYAueAEoGdAG4ok-GPIRQVBJTz6D2bOTCQIAZgRhYl9Vev5KpWLTB178wUJFgB1KCR8TUZECkwcPCJScjRKQhB8CwBzGAAfDwBXAFsAIxtMvJQUABsoURogA.

Comment: `string & number & true & false` really *is* `never`, but before TS3.6 the compiler didn't eagerly reduce it.  That changed in [microsoft/TypeScript#31838](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31838).  So it's not really something that needs "fixing", I think

Comment: Now this can be implemented just as `type UnionToIntersection<U> = [U] extends [infer I] ? I : never`

Comment: For what it's worth, I've put in a feature request to have this as a native generic type:  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45132

Comment: This fails with `UnionToIntersection<{ a?: { b?: string }} | { a?: { c?: string }}>`, it should return `{ a?: { b?: string }} & { a?: { c?: string }}` but actually returns a `never`, even though the former is a valid type

Comment: @Ferrybig [I can't reproduce](https://tsplay.dev/NBPZpW)

Comment: @jcalz After further testing,it breaks with [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes) turned on: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4AoKKAChiggA8c4ATfKAIZwQUAPwsA1gC5YASjo0AbkgQ8oMuBEV55nbnxbNpUBHABmeKBnm0lKnvPEZ1UTdtz16oSFAAySJAl8ADFTCHQAWWhaWEQUdCwcAmJSFHIAb0FRGUyAI2yofGBcUwBzKABfSqgAHyhMgQLMogKikrhyqoqqegB6ACoob2h-QJCwyOjXLUt+3qA This is a new option in typescript 4.4:https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html

Comment: @Ferrybig looks like a compiler bug with conditional types and that compiler flag, then, see [here](https://tsplay.dev/mbd64w).  Probably someone should open a GitHub issue about it if there isn't one already.

Comment: I'm trying to isolate the problem, looks like function types have some weird behavior around `undefined` when `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` is enabled.

Comment: @Ferrybig well, looks like it's not about function types at all, but the fact that the compiler is doing weird things with intersections... see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45623#issuecomment-931389122) I added to ms/TS#45623, an existing bug report.  I think it's probably the same, already reported bug, but if not I'll open a new one at some point.

Comment: @Ferrybig looks like [it is fixed](https://tsplay.dev/wRJELw) by [ms/TS#46052](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46052) so it probably won't be an issue in TS4.5+

Comment: Great answer! Wish they had a less obscure/more direct way to achieve this.

Comment: @Trinidad Hi,could you please add link in docs or somewhere you learn from to explain why it can be the way you mentioned ? I don't know the relative key words in docs.

Comment: @jcalz Hi , I really appreciate that I learned a lot from your answers.  I'm still a little confused about **That distributes the union U and repackages it into a new union where all the consitutents are in contravariant position.**, namely we got `UnionToIntersection<'a' | 'b'>` ,according to the distributive property of conditional types and result I think should be `(k: 'a')=>void extends  ((k: infer I) => void ) ? I : never | (k: 'b')=>void extends  ((k: infer I) => void ) ? I : never` , that is , `'a' | 'b'` , but why `'a' & 'b'` ?

Comment: @jcalz the codes in the docs(https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) is like `type Bar<T> = T extends { a: (x: infer U) => void; b: (x: infer U) => void }
  ? U
  : never;  type T21 = Bar<{ a: (x: string) => void; b: (x: number) => void }>; // string & number` in this case, there is no unions  or this is another way of union?

Comment: In both of those examples, the relevant type is in contravariant position (parameter of a function type).  If you have a type like `(k: A)=>void | (k: B) => void | (k: C) => void` and infer `(k: infer I) => void` from it, the only reasonable inference is that `I` is the *intersection* of `A`, `B`, and `C`.  Certainly `((k: A) => void) | (k: B) => void)` is *not* assignable to `(k: A | B) => void`; see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types

Comment: @Archsx Regarding `type UnionToIntersection<U> = [U] extends [infer I] ? I : never`, I will have a look at it, but I'm a bit rusty so please bear with me as I try to remember.

The reason it works seems to be that for any array `[U]` where `U` is a type union, the resulting array *item* type gets unified to be the type-intersection. 

Think of it this way, with `[string | bigint]` the only properties you can safely use are those common to all types. So, while the array can contain any of those, any random element can only the assumed to be `string & bigint`, and that's what `infer I` does.

Comment: That version [does not work](https://tsplay.dev/w8oz0W).  `[U] extends [infer I] ? I : never` will always be `U` as far as I can tell.  If anyone thinks otherwise, they should demonstrate it.

Comment: @Josep although it is nice that jcalz's answer was very helpful to you, please note that if you upvoted more than 2 posts of theirs in a short timespan, you actually set them up for a bad experience because the system will view it as targeted voting and will revert those votes automatically after the reversal script runs the next UTC day. Also please note that serial voting puts you on moderators' radar as this is considered abuse - gladly, your actions are not malicious, so it's unlikely they will incur any penalties, but please do keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: @Josep thanks for the sentiment, but [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/511366) is not allowed and those votes will likely be reverted soon.  You might want to go undo those yourself.

Comment: I mean... I'm sorry, and I won't do that again. Although, the answers that I up-voted definitely deserved an up-vote.... Anyways, I think that I'm a pretty advanced TS developer and I was struggling to find a good solution to the problem. I was able to accomplish something similar using recursion on a Tuple, but IMO this solution is way better and I learned a lot... So, it was a way of showing gratitude.

Comment: @Josep just keep the way how the system works in mind in the future - it's O.K. to want to show gratitude for someone whose post helped you out, but it is considered abuse by the system (to prevent an unfortunately common phenomenon of voting fraud and voting rings), and the threshold for triggering it is very low. It is advisable to keep it mind, especially in tag combinations where a small subset of users are very active - it's very easy to run afoul of the system threshold by simply browsing posts and voting casually.

Comment: Why is the `infer I` needed, and why, once the type is repackaged in the contravariant position, can't we just force the intersection by using `U` directly?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for an insightful answer! Is there a way to rewrite `UnionToIntersection<U>` using explicit [variance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#optional-variance-annotations-for-type-parameters) from TS 4.7? I figure, this might be slightly more verbose, but the code might be more readable, and wouldn't require the "how it works" section.

Answer (score 16):

There is also a very related problem when you would like an intersection of several types, but not necessarily convert unions to intersections. There is just no way to get right to intersections without resorting to temporary unions!

The problem is that types we would like to get an intersection of **might have unions inside**, which will be converted to intersections too. Guards to the rescue:

```js
// union to intersection converter by @jcalz
// Intersect<{ a: 1 } | { b: 2 }> = { a: 1 } & { b: 2 }
type Intersect<T> = (T extends any ? ((x: T) => 0) : never) extends ((x: infer R) => 0) ? R : never

// get keys of tuple
// TupleKeys<[string, string, string]> = 0 | 1 | 2
type TupleKeys<T extends any[]> = Exclude<keyof T, keyof []>

// apply { foo: ... } to every type in tuple
// Foo<[1, 2]> = { 0: { foo: 1 }, 1: { foo: 2 } }
type Foo<T extends any[]> = {
    [K in TupleKeys<T>]: {foo: T[K]}
}

// get union of field types of an object (another answer by @jcalz again, I guess)
// Values<{ a: string, b: number }> = string | number
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

// TS won't believe the result will always have a field "foo"
// so we have to check for it with a conditional first
type Unfoo<T> = T extends { foo: any } ? T["foo"] : never

// combine three helpers to get an intersection of all the item types
type IntersectItems<T extends any[]> = Unfoo<Intersect<Values<Foo<T>>>>

type Test = [
    { a: 1 } | { b: 2 },
    { c: 3 },
]

// this is what we wanted
type X = IntersectItems<Test> // { a: 1, c: 3 } | { b: 2, c: 3 }

// this is not what we wanted
type Y = Intersect<Test[number]> // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

The execution in the given example goes like this

```js
IntersectItems<[{ a: 1 } | { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }]> =
Unfoo<Intersect<Values<Foo<[{ a: 1 } | { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }]>>>> =
Unfoo<Intersect<Values<{0: { foo: { a: 1 } | { b: 2 } }, 1: { foo: { c: 3 } }}>>> =
Unfoo<Intersect<{ foo: { a: 1 } | { b: 2 } } | { foo: { c: 3 } }>> =
Unfoo<(({ foo: { a: 1 } | { b: 2 } } | { foo: { c: 3 } }) extends any ? ((x: T) => 0) : never) extends ((x: infer R) => 0) ? R : never> =
Unfoo<(({ foo: { a: 1 } | { b: 2 } } extends any ? ((x: T) => 0) : never) | ({ foo: { c: 3 } } extends any ? ((x: T) => 0) : never)) extends ((x: infer R) => 0) ? R : never> =
Unfoo<(((x: { foo: { a: 1 } | { b: 2 } }) => 0) | ((x: { foo: { c: 3 } }) => 0)) extends ((x: infer R) => 0) ? R : never> =
Unfoo<{ foo: { a: 1 } | { b: 2 } } & { foo: { c: 3 } }> =
({ foo: { a: 1 } | { b: 2 } } & { foo: { c: 3 } })["foo"] =
({ a: 1 } | { b: 2 }) & { c: 3 } =
{ a: 1 } & { c: 3 } | { b: 2 } & { c: 3 }
```

Hopefully this also shows some other useful techniques.

Answer (score 7):

jcalz' solution to this question is [as always] perfect, however, for those who might not fully understand it, here's a bit more explanation on this quote in his answer:

> Multiple candidates for the same type variable in **contra-variant** positions causes an intersection type to be inferred.

The above tip is actually the main trick used in the definition of the `UnionToIntersection` type, however, the term "contra-variant" was vague to me and Googling didn't give helpful results either, so let's go over it here:

According to Wikipedia:

> Many programming language type systems support subtyping. **Variance refers to how subtyping between more complex types relates to subtyping between their components.** For example, how should a list of Cats relate to a list of Animals? Or how should a function that returns Cat relate to a function that returns Animal?

Let's see the above explanation in code:

```
type A = (a: Animal) => void
type C = (d: Cat) => void
declare let aFunc: A;
declare let cFunc: C;
```

Now which of the below assignments do you expect to be correct?

```
cFunc = aFunc //  [ ]  ✅ [ ]
aFunc = cFunc //  [ ]  ✅ [ ]
```

First make a guess, then read on. :)

Opposite of what we might expect from "Inheritance", where values of a subtype could be assigned to a variable of their supertype, this is not true in the same direction when this variable is a parameter of a function type, and we're assigning "functions" (Wikipedia's intended "complex type"). And interestingly, it is indeed correct in the opposite direction! I.e., `cFunc = aFunc` is the correct one in the snippet above, and `aFunc = cFunc` is wrong.

Now let's see **why `cFunc = aFunc` is the correct one.** The reason it is correct is, when we assign some variable of type Y to some variable of type X, **it would be "correct" only if the new type (Y in this example) doesn't break any of the usages of the old type (X in this example)**. For example:

```
a = new Animal()
c = new Cat()
a = c   // ✅ Not breaking, everywhere an Animal is used, a Cat must be useable too
        // (It is also formally known as the "Liskov Substitution Principle".)
a.eat() // ---> c.eat() ✅ No problem, Cats can eat too
```

Now use this same rule in case of the function types: If you are assigning a function `foo` of function type `Foo`, to a variable `bar` of function type `Bar`, then wherever you've used `bar`, it must remain still useable / valid.

```
declare let foo: (param: Animal): void
declare let bar: (param: Cat): void
a = new Animal()
c = new Cat()

// valid usages of foo:
foo(a) // ✅
foo(c) // ✅

// valid usage of bar:
bar(c) // ✅

foo = bar // ❌ wrong because 
foo(a)    // ❌ this one has not remained useable / valid
          // because foo expects a Cat now, but is receiving an Animal, which is not valid
foo(c)    // ✅

bar = foo // ✅ correct because  all usages of bar remains still useable / valid
bar(c)    // bar expects an Animal now, and has received a Cat, which is still valid
          // ⭐ That's why we say function parameter is a **contra-variant** position for
          // a type, because it reverses the direction of the assignability.
```

So now we can understand why `cFunc = aFunc` is the correct choice!

The fun edge case of this is, you can type a function parameter as `never` and that allows you to assign functions with whatever type for that parameter to it:

```
type Foo = (a: never) => void
type Bar = (a: Function) => void
type Baz = (a: boolean) => void
type Qux = (a: SuperComplexType) => void
declare let foo: Foo
declare let bar: Bar
declare let baz: Baz
declare let qux: Qux
foo = bar // ✅
foo = baz // ✅
foo = qux // ✅
```

A summary of all the three co/contra/in variances using the same Cat and Animal example is:

- **Covariance**: `() => Cat` is assignable to `() => Animal`, because Cat is assignable to Animal; It "preserves the direction of the assignability".
- **Contravariance**: `(Animal) => void` is assignable to `(Cat) => void`, because something that expects an Animal can also take a Cat; It "reverses the direction of the assignability".
- **Invariance**: `(Animal) => Animal` is not assignable to `(Cat) => Cat`, because not all returned Animals are Cats, and `(Cat) => Cat` is not assignable to (Animal) => Animal, because something expecting a Cat cannot take any other kind of Animal.

Now this is how jcalz' `UnionToIntersection` works:

```
type FirstHalfOfUnionToIntersection<U> = U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never
```

This is a distributed conditional (because the type `U` before `extends` is a naked type (appears alone and is not part of some more complex type expression)), so runs the conditional for each of the components of the union, e.g., in case of `X | Y | Z`, it produces `((k: X) => void) | ((k: Y) => void) | ((k: Z) => void)`.

On the second half of the type, it's actually doing this:

```
<A_union_of_some_functions_from_first_half> extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never
```

This is again a distributed conditional, however, here's the interesting part: The type `I` that is being inferred is in a contra-variant position (it is a function parameter), so all possible inferences of it will be intersected!

> Multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred.

E.g., continuing on the same `X | Y | Z` example, the result will be `X & Y & Z`.

Answer (score 5):

I extended @jcalz's answer slightly to get around the boolean issue he described.

```
type UnionToIntersectionHelper<U> = (
  U extends unknown ? (k: U) => void : never
) extends (k: infer I) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type UnionToIntersection<U> = boolean extends U
  ? UnionToIntersectionHelper<Exclude<U, boolean>> & boolean
  : UnionToIntersectionHelper<U>;
```

this basically prevents it from converting the `true | false` under the hood to a `true & false`, preserving the `boolean` nature of it.

Now it will correctly say `UnionToIntersection<boolean>` is `boolean`, not `never`, while still correctly saying `UnionToIntersection<boolean | string>` is `never`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`UnionToIntersection`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#uniontointersectionu) from a brilliant library [utility-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utility-types). (1.5M weekly downloads in 2022/11)

Or similar type `UnionToIntersection` from another gem library [type-fest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-fest) (117M weekly downloads in 2022/11).

Use it as follows:

```
import type { UnionToIntersection } from 'utility-types'
// or
import type { UnionToIntersection } from 'type-fest'

type FunctionUnion = (() => void) | ((p: string) => void)
type FunctionIntersection = UnionToIntersection<FunctionUnion>
// (() => void) & ((p: string) => void)
```

Comment: This answer here is the source for both of those types. This is the 'original' union to intersection :)

Comment: what about Type = 0 | 1?
I get never

Comment: @stackoverflow `UnionToIntersection` changes `0 | 1` into [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `0 & 1` which gives `never`.

Comment: @mrkvon why that? what about 1 & 2? still never?

Comment: @stackoverflow yes, still never. i guess it's because two different constants have no type in common. in practice, result is a type that will satisfy both intersecting types (e.g. `1 & number` => `1`)